# Selecting polygons that meet minimum containment of certain raster cell value using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, shapefile, select

I have a census block shapefile with a land cover TIFF underneath it. The Raster layer has three different cell values. I am trying to select the census blocks that have a minimum of 50% of cells withing its area with a value of 3. I have access to all extension within ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.

Comment: At the moment you don't seem to have question, just statements of what you want to achieve.  You need to give details of what you have tried and are stuck at, or documentation you have read and are confused with etc...

Answer (score 5):

I would [reclassify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) your land cover tiff to remove the cell values you are not interested in so leaving you with a raster where the you only have pixels with your desired value (3), the rest are nodata. You could then use the [Tabulate Area](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool to compute the area of pixels within each polygon. Run the Join Field tool to join the pixel area to your polygon data and then you will be able to select the polygons where there is more than 50% coverage.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: @David Please accept the answer so that it can help others.

Comment: +1 but tabulate area will work without reclass. Worth trying selecting one class in raster table. Hoping for less columns in output.